# Parse XML using DOM and print in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I tried a lot parsing the following XML using DOM. I am not able to print the values of elements. Can anybody help me to print the values of the elements.

Thanks in advance

```
<tns:CustomerDetails xmlns:xe="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:xd="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:tns="http://abc.com/elements" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pf="http://abc.com/Service">
  <tns:CustomerId>360817</tns:CustomerId>
  <tns:CustomerName>ABC Corp</tns:CustomerName>
  <tns:PAN>awap</tns:PAN>
  <tns:Timestamp>2010-05-20T12:20:19Z</tns:Timestamp>
  <tns:RequestId>397</tns:RequestId>
  <tns:PIN>1234</tns:PIN>
</tns:CustomerDetails>
```

My code

```
      File infile = new File("D:\\Cust.xml");
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = dBuilder.parse(infile);
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

  System.out.println("root of xml file " +
                     doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
  System.out.println("==========================");

  NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("CustomerDetails");
  System.out.println(list.getLength());
  Element name = doc.getElementById("CustomerId");
  if (name == null) {
    System.out.println("There is no element with the ID ");
  } else {
    Text text = (Text)name.getFirstChild();
    System.out.println("The ID " + " locates the name " + text.getData());
  }
```

I have tried with

```
Element name = doc.getElementById("tns:CustomerId");
```

also..
i get null while printing

Comment: Why don't you show what you tried?

Comment: hint, the Element class and all the other Node classes don't have a meaningful `toString()` method.

Comment: Post the code you wrote.

Comment: I have updated the code i have written. I am a newbie and lack the basics..

Comment: best way to get the basics is to find a good tutorial (there are thousands of them out there), not post on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing your models here.  `getElementById` is for elements that have an attribute identified by the document's DTD as an ID, and since your document doesn't have a DTD it will never give you anything useful.

Because your document uses namespaces you should use the "NS" methods to extract elements, and for the text contained in an element you can use `getTextContent`

```
  File infile = new File("D:\\Cust.xml");
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  // namespaces - DocumentBuilderFactory is *not* namespace aware by default
  dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
  DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = dBuilder.parse(infile);
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

  System.out.println("root of xml file " +
                     doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
  System.out.println("==========================");

  NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(
        "http://abc.com/elements", "CustomerDetails");
  System.out.println(list.getLength());
  for(int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
    Element custDetails = (Element)list.item(i);
    Element id = custDetails.getElementsByTagNameNS(
        "http://abc.com/elements", "CustomerId").item(0);
    System.out.println("Customer ID: " + id.getTextContent());
    Element name = custDetails.getElementsByTagNameNS(
        "http://abc.com/elements", "CustomerName").item(0);
    System.out.println("Customer Name: " + name.getTextContent());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ian and others for helping me. Its working now.